# Thunderbird inbox still shows messages I moved to another imap folder with a different client

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I'm using different clients to access my email by imap from diferent devices (PC, phone). When I move a message to my archive folder using my phone (using k9mail), the message remains in my inbox in Thunderbird. Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug, please report it by using `ubuntu-bug thunderbird` . See more on [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

To make sure its a bug, see if the message remains in the inbox with the web client